# How do I stop scheduled UI updates if I get new ones?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-interface, drawing

So, I have a resizable window which draws a graph given on live values it calculates. If I make the window bigger, it redraws and scales everything, also when the graph hits a new maxY and maxX, using those as reference points to determine the position of the other points. This works fine, but if I resize the window, and a lot of things are being scheduled for updating, it the window resizes fine, but the Graph mimics what it was supposed to do a couple (up to 4) seconds ago.

If I understand this correctly, every time I invoke my UI thread, which is blocked, and give him new coordinates to draw, it finishes the current one and then goes on to the next one. I see why you would want that, but since the graph is more or less constantly scaling, it is deleting itself every update anyway, so I would save quite some processing power and runtime, if I would just finish every current task and jump over all the accumulated task right to the newest one, since the stored ones are outdated anyway

Is there a way to do this?

I thought of 3 things which might work, of which the third one the only one is, I know will work or, rather, is possible, even if rather slow:

```
// (1) If there is a way to check if the UI thread is busy, I could just not send 
// a new request to draw another line
if(!uithread.busy)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
                                                           new Action(() => this.DrawGraph(new List<List<Coordinates>> { CoordinateListA, CoordinateListB })));
}
```

```
// (2) As soon as UI thread finishes the current task, it jumps to the newest one
```

```
// (3) In my opinion the ugliest solution, I check how long the last drawing took and 
// don't send any draw-requests in that time. I will just wait that certain time and
// just then send him the newest results to draw and measure how long that took
```

If there is no better solution, I think I will go with (3), but since I hope that there is another way, I wanted to ask if maybe someone else here had a similar issue.

Comment: Make DrawGraph abortable by passing a [CancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Would I then just cancel every queued draw-request whenever I get a new one?

Comment: Well, first of all, I'd suspend drawing the graph while resizing, anyway. How frequent do you draw?

Comment: I agree with @Fildor's suggestion. In this sort of scenario, often what one would do is display a cached image, which is resized to fit as the user resizes the visual area. Bitmap resizing can be done much more efficiently than regenerating the cached image and usually can easily keep up with user input. Then once the user's done resizing, go back and start creating a new cached image. You may or may not still find it valuable to be able to cancel that operation, in case the user starts resizing again immediately after they stop a previous resize operation.

Comment: @Fildor about 200 times per second initiallu, decreasing every redraw

Comment: @PeterDuniho I draw my graph on a canvas, with Line newLine = new Line{}; I don't really do anything with images

Comment: 200 times per second for an additional Line or for a complete redraw? If the latter: don't. Find a reasonable maximum redraw interval and introduce a "deadtime" accordingly.

Comment: Well since every new value is changing the Graphs scale, I need to redraw the graph completely.

Comment: _"I don't really do anything with images"_ -- but you should. That's my point. Use `RenderTargetBitmap` to render your graph to an off-screen bitmap. Display the off-screen bitmap, not live drawing objects. Don't change the off-screen bitmap until the user is done resizing.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Never did anything like that but I will try to rebuild it to that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed it. My Architecture saves all the logs, so I do not need to save coordinates, if I need new values I can just, every time I need new Coordinates, calculate them from the Logs. Like this:

```
// beginning of the class
private bool _isDrawing = false;

if (!_graphIsDrawing)
{
    _graphIsDrawing = true;
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
                                               new Action(() => this.DrawGraph(new List<List<Coordinates>> { CoordinateListA, CoordinateListB }, scalingFactors, canvasSize)));
//I need to invoke, since I am working with multiple threads here. Else it
//would be enough to just call 'this.DrawGraph(...)'
}

///////////

public void DrawGraph(List<List<Coordinates>> listOfGraphs, float[] scalingFactor, int[] canvasSize)
{
    lock (_graphDrawLock)
    {
        this._AlgorithmRuntimeViewA.DrawGraph(listOfGraphs[0], scalingFactor, canvasSize);
        this._AlgorithmRuntimeViewB.DrawGraph(listOfGraphs[1], scalingFactor, canvasSize);
        _graphIsDrawing = false;
    }
}
```

Here I lock it again, so not both threads draw at the same time breaking everything. At the end I set _graphIsDrawing to false again, so I can call it again.